# FullText in a Indexed View - Incremental Population

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I've created a indexed view in Sql Server 2008. In order to use incremental population on tables, we need to create a timestamp column. But should I create this timestamp column on the table wich is referenced by the view? If so, should the view return the timestamp column (maybe sql needs to query the view to get the timestamp column, and because of that i need to return it in my view).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want the timestamp column created on the base table so that it is updated every time a row is modified. You should also return the timestamp column in the view as it will be used by the fulltext engine to identify which rows have changed since the last population.

From [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142575.aspx):

> SQL Server uses the timestamp column
>   to identify rows that have changed
>   since the last population. The
>   incremental population then updates
>   the full-text index for rows added,
>   deleted, or modified after the last
>   population, or while the last
>   population was in progress.
>   ...
>
> At
>   the end of a population, the Full-Text
>   Engine records a new timestamp value.
>   This value is the largest timestamp
>   value that SQL Gatherer has
>   encountered. This value will be used
>   when a subsequent incremental
>   population starts.

Comment: Are you really sure that I also need to return the timestamp column in the view? This will make me do everything I've done so far again ... :)

Comment: @Rafael: See my edited answer. I've added some additional detail on how the fulltext engine uses the timestamp.

Comment: @Joe: Yes, I knew that. But I am not sure that the view needs to return this timestamp, as it makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Rafael: The fulltext index is created on the view, the fulltext index needs the timestamp column for incremental population, so the conclusion is that the timestamp column should be returned as part of the view.